# Flutter Widget syntax

Tags: flutter, widget

This is the definition of a widget named ‘header’ in a tutorial I’m working on:

```
AppBar header(context,{bool isAppTitle, String strTitle, hideBackButton = false})
{
  return AppBar(

    // code that defines AppBar

  ); // AppBar
} // header
```

Haven’t found documentation that discusses the initial line … what the meaning/purples of the {} clause inside the ‘heaser  parentheses: AppBar header(context, { … } ).
Can anyone point me to a site that explains?

Comment: That is not a widget that is a function named `header` with the return type `Appbar`

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generically about the language, this is described as such in the Dart language tour documentation here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

"
When defining a function, use {param1, param2, …} to specify named parameters:

/// Sets the [bold] and [hidden] flags ...
void enableFlags({bool bold, bool hidden}
"
This is why you see other things in the language where you reference variables like this:
Container(height: 10, width: 10)
instead of
Container(10,10)

Speaking specifically about the AppBar's parameters, start with reviewing the official documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

Because the parameters you listed aren't listed in the default constructor of the official documentation we're going to be hard-pressed to help you without seeing some code or a link to the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Scott and Adithya, think this has pointed me to the right doco.

I understand that ‘header’ is a function of type AppBar (typed by the AppBar class). Of the parameters in the parentheses: context is a positional parameter; the parameters inside the curly brackets are (optional) named parameters. This squares with the way the parameters are used in the function code, and how they are passed when ‘header’ is called. Feel free to add/comment.

Coming from the Android Studio/Kotlin ‘world’ I’m finding the (perceived) fuzziness between code and widget a ‘learning experience.’ Thanks!